# No sound from Liquid Saffire 56 on OS X

Tags: audio-interfaces, troubleshooting

I am using a Liquid Saffire 56 on a Macbook Pro, running OS X 10.6. I use both Logic 9 and Cubase 4 (and have successfully run them with a Saffire Pro10IO before). However now, I can't get any sound out of the interface.

*Update:* This issue is still reproducible with OS X 10.10 and Saffire Mix Control 3.5.

I installed the Liquid Saffire software and I am able to use Mix Control in combination with the DAWs. I can see the output from the DAW both in the DAW meter and the main mix meter. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

However, there is **no sound from the headphones and the monitors**.

Things I've checked:

- I connected the monitors to the appropriate monitor 1 and 2 jacks. They are definitely fully functional and set to a reasonable volume.
- I made sure the monitor knob on the interface is working - it is set to 100%. No Dim or Mute switch is engaged.
- I followed the guide on Focusrite's website that deals with headphone issues, still no avail.
- I haven't changed any of the settings in Mix Control. Reverting to factory settings does not help.
- Changing the ASIO driver from Saffire to Internal Audio instantly lets me hear sound on the Macbook, so there is definitely no issue on the DAW side.
- The Firewire cable is working as the unit connects and I've used it on my older Saffire Pro before.

The funny thing is that yesterday it was working perfectly. I didn't change anything. Restarting doesn't help either.

Comment: Can the Saffire pro 14 be connected to a reciever from output to input of reciever, new to digital recording totally lost,also using logic 9 ....no sound

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Update, July 2015:* On http://beta.focusrite.com/ you should find a recent version of Saffire Mix Control that apparently fixes the problem. If you don't want to install beta software, read below.

---

You sometimes have to manually **change the sync source to "Internal"** as seen here:

[image]

Sometimes (and I'm sure this is a known bug) you have to manually set it to *SPDIF* and then set it back to *Internal*. I always have to do this when connecting my Saffire, and it has been a problem since several versions of Mix Control.

A very simple troubleshooting test is this: if the "Locked" indicator on the unit does not show, it won't work.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much
To me it has happened
Change the sync and it worked perfect.

Comment: cheers for the answer to this, solved problem for me too!

Comment: thanks a lot for the help !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is so helpful!!  After doing this, it completely solved the issue!  I've been communicating with Focuserite support and I don't believe they are very aware of this glitch, so I passed them along to this link.

Answer (score 1):

At First, slhck's answer had solved my problem which is the same as yours (thanks slhck!), however, this was still not ideal, because I had to go in and change the sync source every time I turned my Saffire 56 on.

After talking with Focusrite Support, I found a more permanent solution, which I will share with you:

**You need to remove your Audio MIDI Setup preferences and have your Mac create new preference files.**

To do this, please do the following:

***Make sure that ALL audio programs are closed and not running***

1. Navigate to Macintosh HD> Library> Preferences> Audio> *Delete both of the .plist files in this folder**
2. With Finder open, click on the "Go" Menu, hold the "Option" key on your keyboard (exposing the Library) and choose Library> Preferences> Delete the "com.apple.audio.AudioMIDISetup.plist" file

Once this is done, restart your Mac.

*This completely fixed my issues, hopefully it will do the same for you*

Comment: Didn't work for me, unfortunately. I will contact support to see what they have to say.